# python - infinite coin flip that stops when number of heads = number of tails

Tags: python, flip, coin-flipping

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a coinflip loop which will keep flipping and counting the number of flips until the number of heads = the number of tails, where it will stop and print the total number of flips it took to reach that. I'm trying to get the results in order to work on my maths coursework, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to stop or print the results, and when I do it prints 0. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import random
heads = 1
tails = sum(random.choice(['head', 'tail']) == 'tail'
count = 0
while True:
    coinresult = random.randint(1, 2) if heads == tails:
    break

print("The number of flips was {count}".format(count = heads + tails))
```

Comment: You are essentially doing a random walk. It can take a long time for it to terminate. I ran James Kent's algorithm 20 time and had two walks in the thousands.

Comment: i ran the walk recursively 100 times, the average run was 360ish, as you say the highest was in the thousands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what is going on with your indentation but try this:

```
import random
heads = 0 #initialize the count variables
tails = 0

while True:
    coinresult = random.randint(1, 2) #flip coin
    if coinresult == 1: #if result = 1 then increment heads counter
        heads += 1
    elif coinresult == 2: #if result = 2 then increment tails counter
        tails += 1
    if heads == tails: #check if counts are equal and break loop if they are
        break

print("The number of flips was {count}".format(count = heads + tails))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
import random

def flips():
    while True:
        yield (random.getrandbits(1)<<1) - 1

def cumsum(seq):
    s = 0
    for i in seq:
        s += i
        yield s

def length(seq):
    n = 0
    for _ in seq:
        n += 1
    return n

print("The number of flips was {}".format(length(it.takewhile((0L).__cmp__, cumsum(flips())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a nice implementation

```
import random

s = 0
iteration = 0
while True:
    coin = random.sample([-1,1], 1)[0]
    s = s + coin
    iteration = iteration + 1
    if s == 0:
        break

print(iteration)
```